# In scala, Can I say Future and Promise are also kind of monad?

Tags: scala, monads

I have been struggling into understanding of monad.

And, I concluded monad is box of values in which operates some specific task.

so, Can I say Future and Promise are also kind of monad?

Comment: Extremely accessible intro to monads: http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html.

Comment: If Promise refers to the JS Spec, it is not a monad: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50173415/1614973

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `Promise` but `Future` is considered monadic.
https://www.precog.com/blog/Precog-Copointed-The-Abstract-Future/

Comment: Links are fine and all, but it would be useful to get the gist of the post recorded in your answer.