# What are the implications of the recursive joining of Promises in terms of Monads?

Tags: javascript, haskell, promise, monads, es6-promise

I know that Javascript's promises are technically neither functors nor monads in the sense of Haskell, because (among other things)

- they include a `bind` operation that falls back to `map` when a pure function is passed in (and thus has an ambiguous type)
- both the `Promise` constructor and `resolve` (aka `return`) join nested promises recursively

The first issue can easily be bypassed by always providing a function with the right type `a -> Promise b`.

The second issue obviously violates the parametricity trait of parametric polymorphic functions, i.e. one cannot construct a `m (m a)` structure. But what would this structure mean in the context of promises/asynchronous computations? I cannot think of a meaningful semantics for `Promise (Promise a)`, where `Promise` is a monad. So what do we lose? What are the implications of the recursive joining?

Provided we are pretty pragmatic (and that's what we should be when we're programming Javascript), can't we claim that a `Promise` is a monad in Javascript if we take care of the edge cases?

Comment: I would consider that to be a monad. Being used to Haskell, I find the automagic processing (join, map) a bit confusing, but underneath that magic there's still a monad. I guess if I really wanted a less magic behavior I could wrap the promise inside some object, and construct something like `m (Identity (m a))`, so that the join does not happen. Inconvenient, but doable.

Comment: Well, do the laws hold? That's all you have to check.

Comment: As you've noted, for promises to have any chance of being a monad, you'll have to do some handwaving. So begin with some hypothetical operations similar to the ones implemented by promises (i.e. `return` which doesn't also `join`, `bind` which has an unambiguous type) and then prove the monad laws for these functions. Once you've done that, attempt to concretely implement these in terms of actual promise functions. In my mind, this would be a reasonable proof - the 1st (and more important) part being formal, the 2nd being 'informal' or hand-wavy.

Comment: "*I cannot think of a meaningful semantics for `Promise (Promise a)`*" - they're the same semantics as for any other `Promise x`, and that's what makes them meaningful.

Comment: @Zeta Indeed, and in this case the laws don't hold: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50173415/1614973

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The first issue can easily be bypassed by always providing a function with the right type `a -> Promise a`.

Or by not using `then` as the `bind` operation of the monad, but some type-correct ones. [Creed](http://blog.briancavalier.com/creed/) is a functionally minded promise library that provides `map` and `chain` methods which implements the [Fantasy-land spec](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land) for algebraic types.

The second issue can be bypassed as well with the same approach, by not using `resolve` but `fulfill` instead, and the static `of` method as the unit function.

> But what would this structure mean in the context of promises/asynchronous computations?

It's a promise for a promise for a value. Not every constructible type needs to be "meaningful" or "useful" :-)

However, a good example of a similar type is provided by the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API): it returns a promise that resolves to a `Response` object, which again "contains" a promise that resolves to the body of the response.

So a `Promise (Promise a)` might have only one success result value, which could as well be accessed through a `Promise a`, however the two levels of promises

- might fulfill at different times, adding a "middle step"
- might reject with different causes - e.g. the outer one representing a network problem while the inner one represents a parsing problem

Notice that the `Promise` type should have a second type variable for the rejection reason, similar to an `Either`. A two-level `Promise err1 (Promise err2 a)` is quite different from a `Promise err a`.

> I know that Javascript's promises are technically neither functors nor monads in the sense of Haskell

You haven't mentioned the biggest issue yet, however: they're mutable. The transition from pending to settled state is a side effect that destroys referential transparency if we consider execution order, and of course our usual use cases for promises involve lots of IO that isn't modelled by the promise type at all.

```js
Promise.delay(50).then(() => Promise.delay(50))
// does something different than
const a = Promise.delay(50); a.then(() => a)
```

Applying the monad laws is fun and occasionally useful, but we need lots of pragmatism indeed.

Comment: "_destroys referential transparency if we consider execution order_". This is very interesting. I need to reason about it...

Comment: Also when promises are nested the inner ones would be able to access the outer promises scope. This might be useful to pass values directly without using global variables or returning objects by means of object destructuring to pass multiple arguments to the next `.then` stage.

Comment: @Redu Not sure, do you mean that in `ppx.then(px => px.then(x => …` the `px` promise is scope? I don't see how that's particularly useful. We [can always "pass" values by simply nesting `then` calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250687/1048572), similar to what `async`/`await` or monadic `do` notation desugar, we don't need promises of promises for that.

Comment: I dont think in JS by any means you can do like `ppx.then(px => px.then(x => ...)` at least not in the sense of `Promise err1 (Promise err2 a)`.

What i'd meant was `Promise.resolve(2).then(v => (y = (x => 2*x)(v), Promise.resolve(y+3))).then(v => console.log(v));`. Where the nested promise depends on the resolution of the previous. In Haskell though my promise data type would be like `data Promise a b = Resolve a | Reject b` for instance where `a` in fact could be a data type including another promise.

Comment: @Redu Yes, you cannot do `Promise err1 (Promise err2 a)` with native promises, but that's exactly what we're talking about here. The thing you did with the (global) `y` variable has nothing to do with promises, you can do that in any function.

Comment: @Bergi Well sorry... obviously it was meant to be `var y`. By the way i think Haskell promise type would look more JS ish if defined like `data Promise a b = Resolve a b | Reject b` or would it be more meaningful if done like `data Promise a b = Then a b | Catch b`..?

Comment: @Redu It's more like `newtype Promise a b = Promise (Mvar (Either a b))` I think

Comment: "Applying the monad laws is fun and occasionally useful, but we need lots of pragmatism indeed." --- There is a lot of pragmatism in using monads for writing safe and composable code. And less pragmatism in spending time on debugging and fixing subtle errors due to leaky abstractions.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev Leaky abstractions still allow writing composable code, that's why I said they're useful. If you want to reason about safety and concurrency, then promises are probably the wrong monad type for it.

Comment: They are certainly useful but having proper monad/functor with chain/map methods would likely have been more useful and safer. Promises are basically written for people too lazy to distinguish between `map` and `chain`, but there is price to pay in which it is harder to see the code intention and catche subtle errors due to the magic.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev Oh, you were referring to that. Yes, I'd prefer `chain`+`map` as well, but even an implementation like Creed that heeds the type signatures cannot provide true monadic promises - the abstraction is leaky as explained in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I wonder what you think of https://github.com/dmitriz/cpsfy as replacement for promises? It is meant to provide all promises' benefits along with correct functional interfaces (and going beyond functors and monads towards their multi-args versions.)

Answer (score 1):

> I know that Javascript's promises are technically neither functors nor monads in the sense of Haskell

[Not only in the sense of Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50173415/1614973), in any other way as well.

> - they include a bind operation that falls back to map when a pure function is passed in (and thus has an ambiguous type)

there is no `bind` operator provided by JS native promises

> - both the Promise constructor and resolve (aka return) join nested promises recursively

I presume you mean unwrapping "theneables", i.e. calling functions stored under `then` prop whenever there is such function.

> The first issue can easily be bypassed by always providing a function with the right type `a -> Promise b`.

This would not resemble `map` e.g. when `map(f)` is used for 
`f = x => {then: a => a}`.

> The second issue obviously violates the parametricity trait of parametric polymorphic functions, i.e. one cannot construct a `m (m a)` structure.

Indeed.

> But what would this structure mean in the context of promises/asynchronous computations? I cannot think of a meaningful semantics for `Promise (Promise a)`, where `Promise` is a monad. So what do we lose? What are the implications of the recursive joining?

You need to allow storing arbitrary values. Promises are not allowed to store theneables (without unwrapping), which is the problem. So you need to change semantics of both objects and methods. Allow objects to store theneables without change and implement `.bind` aka `.chain` that unwraps (or joins) theneables precisely once - no recursion.

This is what [`creed`](https://github.com/briancavalier/creed) does for promise-like objects and [`cpsfy`](https://github.com/dmitriz/cpsfy) for callback-based (aka continuation passing style) functions.

---

> Provided we are pretty pragmatic (and that's what we should be when we're programming Javascript), can't we claim that a Promise is a monad in Javascript if we take care of the edge cases?

Writing safe, succinct and composable code is pragmatic. Risking introduce subtle bugs via leaky abstractions that might crash critical software with far going consequences is not. 
Every edge case is a potential source of such risk.

In that respect, claiming that `Promise` is a monad does more harm than help, beside being incorrect. It does harm because you cannot safely apply monadic transformations to promises. E.g. it is unsafe to use any code conforming to the monadic interface with promises as if they were monads. If used correctly, monads are there to help abstracting and reusing your code, not to introduce lines of checking and hunting for edge cases.