# How to transform an imperative Promise to a functional Task?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I want to transform an imperative `Promise` to a functional `Task` in a principled fashion:

```js
const record = (type, o) =>
  (o[type.name || type] = type.name || type, o);

const thisify = f => f({});

const taskFromPromise = p =>
  Task((res, rej) =>
    p.then(res)
      .catch(x => rej(`Error: ${x}`)));

const Task = task => record(
  Task,
  thisify(o => {
    o.task = (res, rej) =>
      task(x => {
        o.task = k => k(x);
        return res(x);
      }, rej);
    
    return o;
  }));

const tx = taskFromPromise(Promise.resolve(123)),
  ty = taskFromPromise(Promise.reject("reason").catch(x => x));
//                                              ^^^^^ necessary to avoid uncaught error
  
tx.task(console.log); // 123
ty.task(console.log); // "reason" but should be "Error: reason"
```

The resolution case works but the rejection doesn't, because `Promise`s are eagerly triggered. If I dropped the `catch` handler I would have to put the entire computation into a `try`/`catch` statement. Is there a more viable alternative?

Comment: Your `task` method expects two parameters but you're passing only one argument.

Comment: I don't see how your `Task` is "less imperative" or "more functional" than a promise. If you can transform back and forth between them, they're equal for most purposes. What's the intended difference?

Comment: `Promise` immediately invokes the passed function, whereas `Task` creates a form of function composition. Both are fundamentally different operations and I won't list the consequences, since you are most certainly aware of them. Maybe you think `Task` is imperative, because it causes a local mutation to enable sharing. I am not sure yet if multicast is a harmful or desirable property. The answer probably depends on whether you need cancellation or not.

Comment: Yes, your `Task` is just a `Promise` with lazy initial execution, not a function. It is this mutation and the sharing of the results of an asynchronous effect that [breaks the monad properties for promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45772042/1048572) and makes them imperative tools. (Also your sharing is broken, since it doesn't happen before the promise is fulfilled, and also doesn't consider rejections).

Comment: Running a `Task` is the runtime of Javascript. There is no RT at runtime, because all effects are released. Don't sharing the rejection case is a design decision. _Also your sharing is broken, since it doesn't happen before the promise is fulfilled_ - this is a biased statement. `Task`s are no promises. Sharing is only meant for limited use cases.

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at the `Task` designs in some functional js libraries. Your tasks are muddling in between that and promises, they're neither fish nor fowl.

Comment: I am not interested in an implementation that sticks to pure theory. My `x.task` is like `unsafePerfomIO`. It is the hinge between pure code and runtime. We have no `IO` type in JS so we have to create our own runtime. How to make this more reliable is a matter of research for me. So if you say `o.task = k => k(x)` is broken I will keep that in mind. I nonetheless think a certain amount of pragmatism is not only okay but necessary in a non-purely functonal language like JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `.catch(x => x)`, which turns your rejected promise into an resolved one. You shouldn't get an "uncaught error" since you have a `catch` inside your `taskFromPromise` function. Removing the `.catch(x => x)` does work and lands you in `` .catch(x => rej(`Error: ${x}`)) `` instead.

However removing `.catch(x => x)` does throw "TypeError: rej is not a function". From your code sample it it seems like your `.task(...)` (in `tx.task(...)` and `ty.task(...)`) expects two functions. The first one is called if the promise resolves, the second one if the promise is rejected. Providing both functions leaves me with a working code snippet.

```js
const record = (type, o) =>
  (o[type.name || type] = type.name || type, o);

const thisify = f => f({});

const taskFromPromise = p =>
  Task((res, rej) =>
    p.then(res)
      .catch(x => rej(`Error: ${x}`)));

const Task = task => record(
  Task,
  thisify(o => {
    o.task = (res, rej) => // expects two functions
      task(x => {
        o.task = k => k(x);
        return res(x);
      }, rej);
    
    return o;
  }));

const tx = taskFromPromise(Promise.resolve(123)),
  ty = taskFromPromise(Promise.reject("reason")); // removed .catch(x => x)

tx.task(console.log, console.log); // provide two functions
ty.task(console.log, console.log);
//         ^            ^ 
//      if resolved  if rejected
```

Comment: I really no nothing about `Promise`s. I figured a rejected promies throws immeditaley if there is no catch handler directly attached. Sorry for the rookie question.