# Return Promise in async function in JavaScript (es2017)

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I'm wondering if there is any semantic difference between the 2 functions below in ES2017 or later:

```
async function returnBool() {
    const promise = new Promise(((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res(true);
        }, 1000);
    }));
    // returns a boolean
    return await promise;
}

async function returnPromise() {
    const promise = new Promise(((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res(true);
        }, 1000);
    }));
    // returns a boolean wrapped in a promise
    return promise;
}
```

I tested both versions on Node and they appear to behave the same. However, I'm looking for some assurances that both versions are syntactically and semantically correct.

In languages such as C#, there is always a discrepancy between the declared return type (`Task<TResult>`) and the actual return type in the body (`TResult`) in an `async` method. Judging from the example above, it seems to be not the case in Javascript? Could this suggest a lack of rigor with JS? What if I want to return a `Promise<Promise<T>>` from an async method? (unlikely, but still)

It would be really great if anyone could point to some docs or language standard to clarify this. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between \`return await promise\` and \`return promise\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708550/difference-between-return-await-promise-and-return-promise)

Comment: `async` functions always return a promise. There is no functional difference between an `async` function and a function returning a promise. The only thing `async` allows you to do is use `await`. So use the second implementation and drop `async`.

Comment: use return promise.

Comment: Josh Wilson yes its a duplicate

Comment: "*What if I want to return a `Promise<Promise<T>>` from an async method?*" That is not possible with promises, since they automatically and recursively flatten/join. If you have `new Promise(res1 => res1(new Promise(res2 => res2(42) )))` that simply a single level promise that produces `42` in the end. In many cases, that's fine, but whether it's completely correct [might be up for debate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45770915). The advantage is some simplicity in chaining. The disadvantage is that sometimes you may want something more advanced.

Comment: @VLAZ I did not know that! Thanks a lot for the info!

Answer (score 1):

`async` functions always return a `Promise`. If you return a value that is not itself a `Promise`, it will be wrapped in a `Promise` and that `Promise` will be returned from the `async` function.

In second code example, you are explicitly returning a `Promise` which is unnecessary because, as mentioned above, `async` functions always return a `Promise`