# Typescript: How to kleisli compose (monadic compose) Promise monad using fp-ts

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

How can I compose two kleisli arrows(functions) `f:A -> Promise B` and `g: B -> Promise C` into `h:A -> Promise C` using *fp-ts*?

I’m familiar with Haskell so I would ask in this way: What’s the equivalent of `>=>`(fish operator)?

Comment: Is [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/fp-ts-rightfish-v82x0?file=/src/index.ts) what you're looking for?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please elaborate about what you want.

Comment: @jcalz `monad.chain(f(a), g);` this part was what I was looking for. Thank you.
Also I figured that I could use *Task* rather than implementing a whole Monad for Promise.

Comment: @Ingun전인건 I think FP-TS has a hard time inferring types in the context of point-free style ([GitHub Issue](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/issues/477)), so you have to compose your arrows ad-hoc and manually. Besides, you probably only need to implement your own async type if you want an individual type with in parallel operational semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promises are represented by [`Task`](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/1c2846f/docs/modules/Task.ts.md) or [`TaskEither`](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/a5f06e7/docs/modules/TaskEither.ts.md) monads in `fp-ts`, which are asynchronous computations. `TaskEither` additionally models failure and is the same as `Task<Either<...>>`.

Kleisli Arrows can be composed via [`chain`](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/a5f06e7/docs/modules/TaskEither.ts.md#chain) operation of monads and [`flow`](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/8c86df5/docs/modules/function.ts.md#flow) (pipe operator). The result resembles the application of [`>=>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-) operator in Haskell.

Let's do an example with `TaskEither`:

```
const f = (a: A): Promise<B> => Promise.resolve(42);
const g = (b: B): Promise<C> => Promise.resolve(true);
```

Convert functions returning `Promise` to ones returning `TaskEither` using [`tryCatchK`](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/a5f06e7/docs/modules/TaskEither.ts.md#trycatchk) <sup>1</sup>:

```
import * as TE from "fp-ts/lib/TaskEither";
const fK = TE.tryCatchK(f, identity); // (a: A) => TE.TaskEither<unknown, B>
const gK = TE.tryCatchK(g, identity); // (b: B) => TE.TaskEither<unknown, C>
```

Compose both:

```
const piped = flow(fK, TE.chain(gK)); // (a: A) => TE.TaskEither<unknown, C>
```

Here is a copy paste block for [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-volhard-s6fky?file=/src/index.ts):

```js
// you could also write:
// import { taskEither as TE } from "fp-ts";
import * as TE from "fp-ts/lib/TaskEither";
// you could also write:
// import {pipeable as P} from "fp-ts"; P.pipe(...)
import { flow, identity, pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";
import * as T from "fp-ts/lib/Task";

type A = "A";
type B = "B";
type C = "C";
const f = (a: A): Promise<B> => Promise.resolve("B");
const g = (b: B): Promise<C> => Promise.resolve("C");

// Alternative to `identity`: use `toError` in fp-ts/lib/Either
const fK = TE.tryCatchK(f, identity);
const gK = TE.tryCatchK(g, identity);

const piped = flow(fK, TE.chain(gK));

const effect = pipe(
  "A",
  piped,
  TE.fold(
    (err) =>
      T.fromIO(() => {
        console.log(err);
      }),
    (c) =>
      T.fromIO(() => {
        console.log(c);
      })
  )
);

effect();
```

#### Why no promises?

JavaScript Promises don't adhere to a [monadic API](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land), for example they are [eagerly computed](https://github.com/fluture-js/Fluture/wiki/Comparison-to-Promises) <sup>2</sup>. In functional programming side effects are delayed as long as possible, so we need to use a compatible wrapper in form of `Task` or `TaskEither`.

---

<sup>1</sup> `identity` just forwards the error in failure case. You could also use [`toError`](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/1c2846f/docs/modules/Either.ts.md#toerror).
<sup>2</sup> [Incorporate monads and category theory #94](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/94) is worth reading, if you are interested in historical reasons.

Comment: "*JavaScript Promises don't adhere to a monadic API*" for more reading [Why are Promises Monads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45712106) and [What are the implications of the recursive joining of Promises in terms of Monads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45770915)

Comment: Please note that long `Task` sequences build huge deferred function call trees that may blow the stack when evaluation is triggered.