# Is the JavaScript `then` the same as Haskell `fmap`?

Tags: javascript, haskell, functional-programming

In JavaScript, Promises have a method called `then`, which is used to unpack the result in case of success, for example,

```
fetch("google.com").then(console.log)
```

From [this Haskell's tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids), I also found a similar thing which is called `fmap`, for example,

```
fmap putStrLn (fetch "google.com")
```

They look pretty similar, but I am not sure if they are **equivalent**. That's why I wanted to ask if they are the same thing.

PS: The term **equivalent** shall be that of the Curry-Howard Correspondence kind of equivalent.

Comment: If you go to new teacher then don't remind of old teacher.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar What is wrong with this question? Does it violates any StackOverflow question asking guideline?

Comment: I'm not sure how this violates but pretty sure this doesn't fit for SO. But I was just  suggesting you that you should not compare one language with another. Otherwise, you'll get much difficult in your learning curve.

Comment: Yes, this is the case. Note that `.then` is overloaded, so it ends up playing the role of both `fmap` and `>>=` (promises form a monad - see `Async` for a Haskell analogue).

Comment: [Wise tautology #0](http://www.vex.net/~trebla/humour/tautologies.html): "X is like Y" can always be argued to be true. Furthermore, when X≠Y, "X is unlike Y" can also be argued to be true.

Comment: @DanielWagner So, should your wise tautology be applied to [Curry-Howard correspondance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) as well?

Comment: @WongJiaHau If you can define your use of "equivalent" as carefully as Curry and Howard defined their use of "equivalent" I'll be happy to take a stab at answering your question.

Comment: The Bluebird documentation touches on the subject: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/coming-from-other-languages.html#haskell

Comment: Your Haskell code looks wrong - I'm certain it should be `fetch "google.com" >>= putStrLn`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are Promises Monads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45712106/1048572)

Comment: No, they are not equivalent in the Curry-Howard sense: in fact, neither of them appear to even be well-formed terms in either combinatory types nor intuitionistic implicational logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are related, yes. But `then` for `Promise`s does several different things that in Haskell would be separate functions, not all from the [`Functor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#t:Functor) class (the one that provides `fmap`).

In Haskell, `Promise` would be a type constructor parameterized by the type of what it eventually returns, like `Promise Int` or `Promise String`.

We could make that type an instance of `Functor`, giving us `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Promise a -> Promise b`. This would let us map a *pure* computation over the result eventually returned by the promise. But it wouldn't let us chain promises! If we try fmapping with a function that returns a promise, say of type `Int -> Promise String`, we would end up with a `Promise` that returned another `Promise` at the end but did not execute it, which is not what we usually want.

We could also make `Promise` an instance of [`Monad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad). `Monad` is a subclass of `Functor`. All `Monad`s are `Functor`s, but not all `Functor`s are `Monad`s. `Monad` would give us the function `>>=` (usually called "bind") that would have type `(>>=) :: Promise a -> (a -> Promise b) -> Promise b`. This would be analogous to a `then` in which the callback returns another `Promise` that is sequenced after the original one.

Comment: I'm not familiar with JS `then`. Would it be fair to say that `then` performs `fmap`, and then performs `join` if the result is still a `Promise`? In such way, we can't really construct a value of type `Promise (Promise a)`, right? (Albeit I think we might obtain `Promise (Identity (Promise a))` to fool `then` into not `join`ing the two `Promise`s.)

Comment: @chi Yes, that's how it works https://promisesaplus.com/#point-45 There was some debate back in the day about how much to "overload" `then`: https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/75#issuecomment-14057356 https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/94#issuecomment-16184572

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring typeclasses, we have the following types in Haskell (we will say having the right Haskell typeclasses corresponds to having a suitable `.then` method in JavaScript):

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
bind :: (a -> f b) -> f a -> f b
```

And in JavaScript we have (made up syntax):

```
.then :: (this :: f a) -> (a -> (b || f b)) -> f b
```

So in one sense they are equivalent, but in another not. For example, suppose some kind of promise type called `P` in Haskell and we want to read a URL from a file and then give a promise of fetching that URL:

```
read :: String -> P String
fetch :: String -> P String
readFetch :: String -> P (P String)
readFetch file = fmap fetch (read file)
```

And then later you might `do`:

```
fetched <- readFetch someFile
...
foo <- fetched
```

While in JavaScript if you did `read(file).then(fetch)` this would be equivalent to the following Haskell:

```
readFetch :: String -> P String
readFetch file = bind fetch (read file)
```

So the first only becomes fulfilled once the file is read but the second once the fetch is complete (i.e. later).

We conclude that `then` is similar but not exactly the same as `fmap`.