# Why a promise is pending when there is an object with key name "then"

Tags: javascript, promise

JavaScript works strangely in the situation below.

I saw this answer and got this question about Javascript's weird behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50173415/1614973

I found that if we change the `then` in his code to any other key name we will get a totally different result.
CodePen demo: [his](https://codepen.io/dmitriz/pen/QrMawp?editors=0011), [changed](https://codepen.io/DDElephant/pen/PgeVXp)

I tried Chrome and Firefox and they all have this problem.
I explorer the problem there and find some basic rules of this "bug".

```js
// This one will always pending
const pendingPromise = Promise.resolve(x=>x).then(r => ({ then: y => 0 }));
pendingPromise.then(r => console.log("promise resolved")); // "promise resolved" will never logged

// Thanks @Jaromanda X's correction. a simpler version is:
const pendingPromise1 = Promise.resolve().then(() => ({then: y => 0}))
pendingPromise1.then(r => console.log("promise1 resolved")); // "promise1 resolved" will never logged
```

The `pendingPromise` is pending forever. There are three things to toggle this bug as far as I can see:

1. <s>The original one must be fulfilled with a function.</s> (unnecessary constraint)
2. In `.then`, an Object with a key of the name "then" must be returned.
3. The value of the key `then` must be a function.

I'd like to get any clue about why this happens.

Comment: `x=>x` and `r` are total irrelevant, so point 1 is wrong ... `pendingPromise = Promise.resolve().then(()=>({then: y => 0}))` behaves identically

Comment: You may get some insight into your error by reading how then method should be implemented https://promisesaplus.com/#the-then-method

Comment: @Jaromanda X  You are right. thanks for the correction. I've changed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it never resolves is because your final "then" never calls resolve:

`.then(r=>({then: y => 0}))` just returns a non-thenable `0`.

`y` is a resolve callback.  To make your code work, change `y` to `resolve` and then call it.  Or, just call `y`.  Point is, until the resolve is called, the promise remains pending.

```js
console.log("Starting Strange Promise")
const pendingPromise = Promise.resolve(x=>x).then(r=>(
  {then: y => "Strange Promise Done!"}
));
pendingPromise.then(console.log) // never happens

console.log("Starting Hacked Promise")
const hackedPromise = Promise.resolve(x=>x).then(r=>(
  {then: resolve => resolve("Hacked Promise Done!")}
));
hackedPromise.then(console.log)  // happens, like, speed of light quickly
```

Comment: to avoid some confusion, it doesn't have to be called `resolve` ... it can be called anything, as it is the `onresolved` callback (one of two) that is passed to then ... therefore the original code would just need to be `{then: y => y(0)}`

Answer (score 1):

We are all familiar with this: in one of the `.then(callback)`, if the callback returns another promise, say `lastPromise`, the whole promise chain (up till that point) will effectively "become" `lastPromise`.

Internally, the promise chain doesn't check if the `lastPromise` thing is a real promise at all. It only check if it implements the *thenable interface* (has a `.then()` method). If it does, then it further *assumes* the method also conforms to the [spec](https://promisesaplus.com/#the-then-method).

> A promise must provide a then method to access its current or eventual value or reason.
>
> A promise’s then method accepts two arguments:
>
> `promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)`

Now you return an object from the callback that has a `.then` method, which makes it a thenable. The promise chain will thus treat this object like a comrade, believe that it is a "promise", call its `.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)` (which is effectively the `(resolve, reject)` pair).

Now a good thenable knows the right thing to do with `(onFulfilled, onRejected)`. Unfortunately they trust the wrong guy. Your implementation goes like:

```
then = (onFulfilled) => 0
```

You never actually call `onFulfilled(someValue)` to resolve from pending state, so since the whole chain now "becomes" `lastPromise`, but your fake `lastPromise` fails to resolve/reject, the whole chain just stucks at pending state for good.

That's the sad story of blindly trust any thenable to be a promise.